# How to print the name of the devices that are connected to my laptop hotspot using python

Tags: python, networking, operating-system

I want to get the names of the devices connected to my laptop hotspot using python

I searched a lot and I find module like wmi and platform that gives you some system information but I couldn't get the job done by them

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It depends on your OS actually.
For windows;
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-getting-all-the-wifi-devices-the-system-has-connected/
For Linux;
https://pypi.org/project/who-is-on-my-wifi/

Comment: i want to get the names of the devices that are connected to my laptop so the laptop is working as a hotspot or as a router  this code gives me the name of the routers that my pc has made conncetion with it but anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Huh okay, please check here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1014088/484887